# ¿Como pasar dos parametros por url en angular 5?

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando pasar dos parametros por url en angular 5 pero no me deja lo estoy haciendo asi

```
 let administrador = this.usuario.admin

 let username = this.usuario.username

 this._http.get(`http://localhost/api/public/archivo/admin/${administrador},
 ${username}`,{headers:headers}).subscribe(data=>{

 }.....
```

Alguna solucion ?

Comment: ¿No un string template va encapsulado de "backticks"? `\`hola ${variable}\``

Comment: Despues de la edición, ¿Sigue sin funcionar? ¿Te muestra algún error en consola?

Comment: ya me funciona..

Comment: ¿Te funcionó por poner los backticks? Lo pondré como respuesta por si le sirve a alguien en el futuro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta a la [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/146608/1)

Un [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) o [Plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) tiene que ir encapsulado por "backticks" o comilla invertida de esta forma

```
`texto ${variable}`
```

De otra forma tomará todo como texto ignorando las variables

Answer (score 2):

No sé si te servirá de ayuda pero, creo que para hacer referencia a esa variable en el archivo .ts, no hace falta que lo metas entre {}, aparte de que para hacer referencia al valor que contiene administrador en el html, sería con doble de esta manera -> {{administrador}}

Por lo que para que coja la variable administrador en el lugar que la estás colocando bastaría con quitarle los {}. Aunque no estoy del todo seguro, ya que yo también estoy peleandome con ionic actualmente.
Aparte de que la segunda variable no la estás colocando dividida con "/", si no que le estas colocando ","

Aún así para saber si las peticiones se realizan correctamente te recomiendo que uses Postman, este te puede ayudar bastante.

Comment: `http://localhost/api/public/archivo/${id},${admin}`  es asi en realidad